# Long running processes on App Engine with Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, web-scraping, cron

I have a Node.js web scraper that might take over an hour to run. It times out trying to run on App Engine standard environment. What's the best way to deploy it?

Also, it it triggered to run once per day with cron.yaml which hits an Express route. Is there a better way to do this?

Here is a simplified snippet of the code. I can run it locally, and deploy it to App Engine. It runs fine with a small amount of links in dlLinkArray. But with a larger amount (thousands) it doesn't seem to do anything. Usage reports show that it runs for a few seconds.

```js
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();

function startDownload(){
    dlLinkArray = [/*Array of objects with URL and Filename {link: 'http://source.com', filename: 'file123456'} */]; //About 10,000 links/files

    var promises = [];

    dlLinkArray.forEach(record =>{ //create array of nested promises
        promises.push(
            uploadFile(bucketName, record.link, record.filename)
            .then((x) => {
                if(x[1].name) //rename file from whatever is on the remote server to a usefull ID
                    return renameFile(bucketName, x[1].name, record.filename + ".pdf"); //renameFile uses storage.file.move to rename, returns a promise
                else
                    return x;
            })
        );
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);
}

function uploadFile(bucketName, fileURL, reName) {
    // Uploads a remove file to the Cloud Storage bucket
    return storage
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .upload(fileURL, {
            gzip: true,
            metadata: {
                cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
            },
        });
}

/*Express Route*/
app.get('/api/whatever/download', (req, res) => {
    buckets2.startDownload().then(() => console.log("DONE"));

    res.status(200).send("Download Started");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem might occur due to the request deadline. For the App Engine standard it is set at 60 seconds by default. However, if you use [manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling), requests can run up to 24 hours in the standard environment.

Comment: Is that the "idle_timeout" setting? Does that have a different limit in basic scaling? 

I set `idle_timeout: 120m` and got an out of range error. But 60m worked.

Comment: There is no need to specify "idle_timeout". The request deadlines are determined by the scaling settings, so the only thing you have to change is the scaling settings and the issue should be resolved.